# How update the column value depending on the value of other column by procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** database I have table called `RELATIONSHIP`:

```
| SURVEY_ID                            | EMPLOYEE | ORGANIZATION_NAME | STATUS (default: false) |
|--------------------------------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------------|
| d5f9c639-13e6-42c1-9043-30783981724b | Mark     | Apple             | false                   |
| d5f9c639-13e6-42c1-9043-30783981724b | Bob      | Apple             | true                    |
```

This table has unique key which you can create by next sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE RELATIONSHIP ADD CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP_UNIQUE_KEY UNIQUE (SURVEY_ID, EMPLOYEE);
```

Lets say I want to add new 3 record by procedure in `RELATIONSHIP` table.

```
CALL creator(
    'd5f9c639-13e6-42c1-9043-30783981724b',
    ARRAY['Mark', 'Bob', 'Kate'],
    ARRAY['Google', 'Google', 'HP']
);
```

If `SURVEY_ID` and `EMPLOYEE` values are unique and there is no such record in the table I want to add that record to the table. For example third record wasn't in table in the beginning. For thats why I add it. In the same time if `SURVEY_ID` and `EMPLOYEE` values are not unique and there was such record in the table I don't want to add them. For example first and second records. The problem is that I need to update value of `ORGANIZATION_NAME` column if status is true. For example first record's status false. For thats why I need to update the value of `ORGANIZATION_NAME` column from Apple to Google. The second record does not change. How to make this update correctly?

Other word, I want such result finally:

```
| SURVEY_ID                            | EMPLOYEE | ORGANIZATION_NAME | STATUS (default: false) |
|--------------------------------------|----------|-------------------|-------------------------|
| d5f9c639-13e6-42c1-9043-30783981724b | Mark     | Google            | false                   |
| d5f9c639-13e6-42c1-9043-30783981724b | Bob      | Apple             | true                    |
| d5f9c639-13e6-42c1-9043-30783981724b | Kate     | HP                | false                   |
```

Right now my procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE creator(SURVEY_IDENTIFIER uuid, EMPLOYEES VARCHAR[], ORGANIZATION_NAMES VARCHAR[]) AS $FUNCTION$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP (SURVEY_ID, EMPLOYEE, ORGANIZATION_NAME) 
        SELECT 
            SURVEY_IDENTIFIER SURVEY_ID,
            EMPLOYEE FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[EMPLOYEES]) EMPLOYEE,
            ORGANIZATION_NAME FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[ORGANIZATION_NAMES]) ORGANIZATION_NAME
        ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP_UNIQUE_KEY 
        DO NOTHING;
    END;
$FUNCTION$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

**PROBLEM**:

```
SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time Tip: Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.
```

The problem is partially solved after adding `SELECT DISTINCT` as you adviced.

If I call procedure with such values there is no error:

```
CALL creator(
  '99c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9',
  ARRAY['Mark', 'Kate', 'Mark'],
  ARRAY['NEXT', 'U12', 'NEXT']
);
```

The problem is teal the same if I call procedure with such values:

```
CALL creator(
  '99c89a24-fff2-4cbc-a542-b1e956a352f9',
  ARRAY['Mark', 'Kate', 'Mark'],
  ARRAY['NEXT', 'U12', 'HP']
);
```

What can be done in this case in your opinion? I think the best way in this case is to set the last value of `ORGANIZATION_NAME`. In mean would be better to set `HP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the `ON CONFLICT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO RELATIONSHIP (SURVEY_ID, EMPLOYEE, ORGANIZATION_NAME) 
    SELECT SURVEY_IDENTIFIER as SURVEY_ID,
           u.EMPLOYEE, u.ORGANIZATION
    FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[EMPLOYEES],
                ARRAY[ORGANIZATION_NAMES]
               )  u(EMPLOYEE, ORGANIZATION_NAME)
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP_UNIQUE_KEY 
        DO UPDATE SET ORGANIZATION_NAME = EXCLUDED.ORGANIZATION_NAME
                  WHERE NOT RELATIONSHIP.STATUS;
```

Note that I also changed the `FROM` clause to do a parallel unnesting of the arrays.  I do not recognize the double `FROM` syntax used in the query in your question.

For the last problem, I think this version of the query will work:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.EMPLOYEE) SURVEY_IDENTIFIER as SURVEY_ID,
           u.EMPLOYEE, u.ORGANIZATION
    FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[EMPLOYEES],
                ARRAY[ORGANIZATION_NAMES]
               ) WITH ORDINALITY u(EMPLOYEE, ORGANIZATION_NAME, n)
    ORDER BY u.EMPLOYEE, n DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I seems to me that we need a condition when updating the value of `ORGANIZATION_NAME` column. As I said before in post I need to update the value of `ORGANIZATION_NAME` column only if `STATUS` column of existing record has `false` value. For example Mark's organization name changed, but Bob's organization name not. Do you have any ideas about this moment?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek . . . You can add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Sorry for this question but how correctly I need to call this procedure? In my original post you can notice the example code of how I call procedure. Right now procedure show me such error when I try to run it: `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "u". Where: PL/pgSQL function creator(uuid,character varying[],character varying[]) line 3 at SQL statement`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I changed from `u.ORGANIZATION_NAME` to `excluded.ORGANIZATION_NAME`. Now it say that something wrong with `where` condition: `SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "status" is ambiguous`.

Comment: Well, finally I found 3 mistake. 1) column skipped. Must be: `*** SURVEY_ID, EMPLOYEE, ORGANIZATION_NAME FROM ***`. 2) Instead of  `u.ORGANIZATION_NAME` change to `excluded.ORGANIZATION_NAME`. 3) Also in `where` condition must be `WHERE NOT RELATIONSHIP.STATUS`. Please can you update your answer? I can mark it as correct in that case.

Comment: The only problem which I notice is that procedure raise error if I try to add the same values. `SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time Tip: Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.` I would be grateful to your advice.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek . . . Does `SELECT DISTINCT` solve that problem?

Comment: The problem is partially solved. Can you check my post again please?! I explained why the problem is only partially solved. What can you advice to situation which I described?